# SSIS - How to configure Database connection with alternate AD credentials

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a question with regards to configuring database connections in SSIS to SQL server and using AD credentials other than the regular user account. Is this possible to do, or do i need to use a SQL user account?

Our IT department just recently went through a change and split our user account to have a regular account and admin account. Since then, one of our guy's is struggling with some SSIS packages as well as some PowerBI dashboards that he had created, since now his regular user account no longer has access to the databases.

I'm thinking that it is probably best just to create a SQL user account, but he wanted to try and configure it using his admin credentials. Just wondering what others usually do with respect to this?

By the way we're using SSIS 2014

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is to configure the SSIS host process to run as the target account.  There's no way to embed AD credentials in a connection string, like with SQL Auth.

So in the normal case where SQL Agent runs the SSIS packages, you configure the AD credentials as a SQL Server Credential, and create a [SQL Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-2017).  Then whether the Agent job launches DTEXEC.EXE directly, or calls the SSISDB stored procedures, the package execution will use the AD account of the Proxy, and your connections to SQL Server can use Integrated Security.

Comment: OK, so I have used the SQL Agent Proxy in the past with Integration services tasks that i've deployed to SSISDB...just to make sure that i'm understanding this correctly, are you suggesting that the development of the integration services package be developped using a specific AD account other than the users?

The issue that we have isn't so much with respect to deploying the task on the server, it's more to do with the development of a new SSIS package.

Do you normally just Shift+Right click and run SQL Server Data tools as an other user to do this?

Comment: Continuing... The reason i ask is because when we tried this we still issues with the sql server db connection using windows authentication. Here is the error msg we got

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

this only come up however when we use run as a different user. If you connect direct from the users account it works, but then you're constantly logging out of windows and logging in as another user :(